# Changing motherboard with a different socket type and CPU

Tags: drivers, motherboard, formatting

I'm planning to change my motherboard to a AM3 socket, my socket now is a FM2 do I need to reformat all my drivers or just the driver with the OS on it?

Comment: This entirely depends on your operating system.  Windows has SysPrep and realistically can be used to transfer the installation to new hardware.  You will of course require a new license if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

It’s always recommended to perform a fresh installation on new hardware, this ensures that any potential conflicts between the old driver configuration and the new are eliminated. Even when you prepare a corporate image for deployment to multiple makes and models of computers, it is recommended to create the image in a virtual environment to avoid installation of complex drivers that can cause conflict.

With that said, it is possible. I’d recommend backing up first. I’d also recommend removing any drivers that have entries in Programs and Features to ensure that control applications are removed along with the drivers (which would be removed by Sysprep). You should also verify that the driver for the appropriate storage controller mode is enabled in the environment before transferring it. For example, if your current motherboard uses AHCI and on the new motherboard you intend to use RAID, you’ll need to enable the RAID driver via the registry before you move or you’ll encounter a BSOD when you try to boot on the new computer.